# Is a DEFAULT constraint an actual constraint?

Tags: sql, database, constraints

In SQL I see several types of constraints, like PRIMARY KEY. NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY, etc. But I stumbled on DEFAULT constraints now and I'm confused.

What does it prevent to happen? Will any query fail to adhere by it?

If no query will ever fail because of a DEFAULT constraint, is it really a constraint?

Thank you.
A confused developer

Comment: Depends on the database platform you are using. Your question doesn't specify. Some databases using the default constraint only on insert. Others respect the constraint on insert and update.

Answer (score 0):

if a column is `Not NULL`

Like

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (val int NOT NULL)
```

and you try

```
 INSERT NTO mytable VALUES (NULL)
```

You will get an error, as te database can't replace the NULL with a `DEFAULT` value, because it doesn't exist.

so it constraints the `INSERT INTO`

Comment: So, the presence of a default constraint does not prevent anything, but its absence can. I see.

Comment: Yes it prevents you from entering null values, also it allows you to insert rows with out mentioning the column and it still gets a value as per eefinition

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following answer helps you understanding about DEFAULT constraint.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213316/7056491

Comment: I think this link describes benefits of having a DEFAULT constraint, but not what is prevents.

Answer (score 0):

If a column has a DEFAULT constraint and the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement doesn’t provide the value for that column, MySQL will use the default value specified in the `DEFAULT` constraint.

So for table:

```
CREATE TABLE Defaults (
    Age int,
    Gender varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Female'
);
```

You can Insert:

```
INSERT INTO Defaults (`Age`) VALUES ('4');
```

Age will be 4, and Gender will be 'Female'.

The DEFAULT constraint does not RESTRICT the addition of any value nor does it enforce a rule like the other constraints, but it does provide **proper predefined values** to keep domain integrity intact.

Comment: The second part about the `NULL` is not necessary true. You can insert NULL to any column which is not defined as `NOT NULL` (or explicitly defined nullable) in most RDBMS. The `DEFAULT` constraint is only used when an `INSERT` statement is not containing the column with the default constraint. Ommitting the column in an `UPDATE` statement will not set the value of the column to the defined default value, but will keep the value stored in it. Default can also be used to populate a newly added column in the table.

Comment: The second half of your answer is not consistent with versions of MySql I have used. I have never seen a default constraint restrict the insert of null values, unless the column also had a not null constraint.

Comment: @Pred and Sam, You're both right. Editing my answer